# jQuery autocomplete using data pulled from SharePoint list using ajax REST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, sharepoint

I need to add autocomplete to an input textbox. The data needs to be fetched from SharePoint using AJAX / REST.

This what I've done so far:

JS

```
var myData = [];
var requestHeaders = {
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
}

$.ajax({
url: "https://my-URL/sites/RMA-GFPLC/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('AD_DB')/items?    $select=Title,Regional_x0020_Office,Commodity,Commodity_x0020_Year,StateLookUp/Title&$expand=StateLookUp",
type: 'GET',
dataType: 'json',
async: false,
headers: requestHeaders,
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {
        myData.push(result.Title);

    });

    myDataSource(myData);


},
error: function ajaxError(response) {
    alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
}
});

function myDataSource(myData){
$('#myAutoCompleteSearch').autocomplete({
source: myData,
minLength: 3
});
}
```

So far my code is not working, and I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null " error in my console. I;m wonder what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when a source for [Autocomplete function](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)  contains an element(s) with a null value.

**Solution**

Add the condition for checking if value is not null:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function (i, result) {
      if(result.Title) {
         myData.push(result.Title);
      }   
});
```

Comment: Good point, because I noticed that it started working with Title, which doesn't have any null value, but it doesn't work with the rest of the fields (columns) may contain null values (empty rows). Brilliant! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Jast insert your code in

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

//your code here
}

Comment: This 3-year old question already has an accepted answer that seems to have solved the problem. Your answer doesn't even answer the question. Please read [How to answer a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)